# Trying to integrate R with my Java application using JRI, but I'm getting error. Can anyone explain the cause and solution?

Tags: java, r, jri

I need to integrate Java with R to run some math commands and make plots using features of R. Following part of code is giving error.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

            HelloRWorld r = new HelloRWorld();
            r.helloRWorld();
    }

    public void helloRWorld() {

            // using rengine to connect to r
            rengine.eval(String.format("greeting <- '%s'", "Hello R World"));
            REXP result = rengine.eval("greeting");
            System.out.println("Greeting from R: "+ result.asString());
    }
```

That's the error I'm getting and have no idea about it. Is this something related to JFrames?
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006c726036, pid=5360, tid=5956

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [R.dll+0x26036]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
D:\Java\R\hs_err_pid5360.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Comment: I was able to run your code. I guess the error comes somewhere outside the snippet you provided.

Comment: Thanks for responding @nicola. I'll check it again.

Comment: did you set up properly the environment variables of JAVA_HOME, PATH and R_HOME? did you enter through vm options the path to JRI, also did you install in Java all the required JAR files (i don't see any imports in your java code)

Comment: @YehoshaphatSchellekens : I was able to execute it. There was another package that needs to installed in R, RUniversal. It worked after that.