# rjava jri, Failed on "save", "saveRDS" commands

Tags: java, rjava, jri

I am using rJava 0.95, with R3.0.1, java 1.8, and my development IDE is Intellij

In my java code I have this line:

```
 org.rosuda.REngine.REXP result = re.parseAndEval("save(myObject,file=\"myoutput.R\")");
```

where "myobject" is a dataset object created by R, and I want to save it to a file and load it back later.

But this line breaks and throws the following error. I would really appreciate some suggestions on how to solve this. Many thanks!

===========================

> R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000077358104,
>   pid=9084, tid=8260
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build
>   1.8.0_31-b13)  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)  Problematic frame:  C 
>   [ntdll.dll+0x18104]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
>   client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   D:\Work\tac\hs_err_pid9084.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.

Comment: Have you properly imported all the needed packages? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329094/trying-to-integrate-r-with-my-java-application-using-jri-but-im-getting-error?rq=1) thread involves the same error, and some of the suggestions might be of help.

Comment: Yes I think I have done all those. My other code that calls R works perfectly, it is just this line that saves an R object to file system fails.